# Importing local package in another folder

Tags: go

I keep getting the following error and I have been trying out some of the other suggestions in other Stack Overflow threads.

> ./main.go:15:13: undefined: checkEnv

Folder Structure:

```
├── README.md
├── main.go
└── validate
    └── args.go
```

$GOPATH

```
/Users/myusername/go
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "projectName/validate"

    "gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "thirsty"
    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
        result := checkEnv(c.Args().Get(0))

        fmt.Println(result)
        return nil
    }
    err := app.Run(os.Args)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

validate/args.go

```
package validate

import "strings"

func checkEnv(environment string) bool {
    env := strings.ToLower(environment)
    return env != "qa" && env != "dev"
}
```

My project is in the src directory of my $GOPATH. If this is not the proper way to do code splitting, is there a generally used convention to follow?

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: 1. checkEnv is not exported. 2. Stick to How to Write Go Code word for word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. The `checkEnv` method is not exported [in validate/args.go]. ie it is usable only inside the same package and not other packages
    To export just capitalize the first letter of the method `CheckEnv`. Now `CheckEnv` can be used from other packages
2. While calling a method from other package, the syntax should be `packagename.ExportedMethod(params...)`. 
   so in your code [in main.go] it should be `result := validate.CheckEnv(c.Args().Get(0))`